# error message showing even though there is data and sometimes when there is none

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So in React i have a simple search. That displays data in an array. And when the search doesn't match i made a message that says "No Results...".

The error message shows when there is data being shown and sometimes not showing despite there is nothing to display.

[image]
[image]

```
...

class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    orgNames: [],
    searchResult: [],
    errorMessage: null,
  };

  ....

  searchHandler = (e) => {
    const searchValue = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    if (!searchValue) {
      this.setState({
        searchResult: [],
      });
    } else {
      const result = this.state.orgNames.filter((orgName) => {
        return orgName.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue);
      });
      this.setState({
        searchResult: result,
      });
    }

    if (searchValue.length >= 0 && this.state.searchResult.length === 0) {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage: "No Results...",
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage: null,
      });
    }
  };

  ...
        {this.state.searchResult.map((res, key) => {
          return (
            <Link key={key} to={"/r/" + res}>
              <li>{res || <Skeleton />} </li>
            </Link>
          );
        })}
        {this.state.errorMessage === null ? (
          ""
        ) : (
          <li>{this.state.errorMessage}</li>
 ...
```

Comment: It looks like the logic you have set is checking if the searchValue is greater than or equal to 0. This should be changed to check if it deeply equals 0.

Comment: you are using multiple setState in a funtion do the nessasory computation the update it once. and also the condition is searchValue.length > 0 not searchValue.length >= 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of I analysed here, you have to do your if  condition checks in the setState callback function. Since setState is an asynchronous function.

```
    searchHandler = (e) => {
    const searchValue = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    if (!searchValue) {
        this.setState({
            searchResult: [],
        });
    } else {
        const result = this.state.orgNames.filter((orgName) => {
            return orgName.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue);
        });
        this.setState({
            searchResult: result,
        },()=>{  console.log("search REa", this.state.searchResult)
            if ( this.state.searchResult.length === 0) {
                this.setState({
                    errorMessage: "No Results...",
                });
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    errorMessage: null,
                });
            }});
    }


};
```

I changed your code little bit and please verify that.

Comment: This worked greatly with a little bit of tweaking. Thanks alot.

Comment: Thank You. Your comment gives me some pleasure. Since this answer got my first vote

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Instead of displaying an error message when there is nothing in the input, how about only displaying it when the input does not match the result?

Without seeing your data I can't give something definitive but maybe something like the below?

```
 if (searchValue !== searchResult || this.state.searchResult.length === 0)
```

The problem with the original code is you're depending on the first condition AND the second condition.

```
//This is already true before anything is in the input, and is also true when there is something in the input
 if (searchValue.length >= 0 && this.state.searchResult.length === 0)
```

The below example moves your condition a bit higher in your function and checks if the value being entered exists in the array. If it doesn't, OR if searchResult returns null then show the error.

```
searchHandler = (e) => {
        const searchValue = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
        if (!searchValue) {
            this.setState({
                searchResult: [],
            });
        }
        //if orgName array does not include search value OR if searchResult length === 0 then display error message
        else if (!orgName.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue) || this.state.searchResult.length === 0) {
            this.setState({
                errorMessage: "No Results...",
            });
        } else {
            const result = this.state.orgNames.filter((orgName) => {
                return orgName.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue);
            });
            this.setState({
                searchResult: result,
            });
        }
```

Comment: I've tried those. it just throws the error message when everything is deleted. And you're left with "No Result..." and not when the state is empty.

Comment: Made some edits above. - The problem lies in that conditional statement, you just have to rework it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it worked for me:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            searchText: '',
            orgNames: ['IBM', 'Google', 'Apple', 'AppleIBMGoogle'],
            searchResult: ['IBM', 'Google', 'Apple', 'AppleIBMGoogle'],
            errorMessage: null,
        };
    }

    searchHandler = (e) => {
        const searchValue = e.target.value;
        const result = this.state.orgNames.filter((orgName) => {
            return orgName.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())
        })

        if (searchValue.length > 0 && result.length === 0) {
            this.setState({
                errorMessage: "No Results...",
                searchText: searchValue,
                searchResult: result,
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                errorMessage: null,
                searchText: searchValue,
                searchResult: result,
            })
        }
    }


    render() {
        const result = this.state.searchResult.map((res, key) => (
                <div key={key}>
                    <li>{res}</li>
                </div>
            )
        )

        console.log(this.state)

        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.errorMessage ? <li>{this.state.errorMessage}</li> : result}
                <input type="text" name='searchText' onChange={this.searchHandler} value={this.state.searchText} />
            </div>
        )

    }
}

export default App
```